# How do you debug Visual Studio + Angular + Firebase + Chrome (browser or app not secure error)?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, google-chrome, firebase-authentication, chrome-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio to debug an Angular application that needs to authenticate through Firebase. I've installed the "Debugger for Chrome" and things are working fine until... I need to login which authenticates via Firebase. At that point Chrome opens a new window (as expected) but after trying to login I get:

"Couldn't sign you in This browser or app may not be secure.
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in."

What's particularly strange/frustrating is that if I run the application without the debugger it appears to use the same installation of Chrome and I don't get the error.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have figured this out, or at least have a usable workaround. 
You need to use the attach request type in the launch.json config of the Debugger for Chrome. This is what mine looks like now...
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Attach to url",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "attach",
          "port": 9222,
          "url": "localhost:4200",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
  ]
}
You also need to modify your shortcut for Chrome and add:
 --remote-debugging-port=9222

Using this attach method is documented in the Debugger for Chrome documentation as well.